# Frappe framework auto calcualte age and fullname

Tags: javascript, erpnext, frappe

Good day,

I need help in solving this  problem

Problem :

I am trying to set up a custom script that calculates the age of the user base on the year it's chosen, Also when the user inputs the first_name , last_name , middle_name it should reflect on full_name.

I tried my best to code it but it's not working, to anyone who is reading this with a golden heart, please help me correct my code.

Addition note: I am using a Frappe framework and running on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

For additional info on where I create custom code and the doctype (client_details)

Screenshots:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1556W7AeeLfaJuC2Fu8RbnI7sSZc4hXQZ?usp=sharing

Thank you so much <3

//my custom code using I'm writing on .js

```
    frappe.ui.form.on('client_details', {

    refresh: function(frm) {
      var today = new Date(); 
      var birthDate = new Date(brith_day); 
      var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear(); var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth(); 
      if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) { 
      age--; 
            } return age;
    }
    
    refresh: function(frm){
      var first_name = first_name
      var last_name = last_name
      var full_name = first_name.concat(last_name)  
      return full_name;
        }       
        
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Two issues in your code

- Using `return` instead of [set_value](https://frappeframework.com/docs/user/en/api/form#frmset_value) for output
- Using multiple refresh events. Since the keys are same, the last one will take effect.

---

Use this code to set the values for `fullname` and `age` on `refresh` event

```
frappe.ui.form.on('client_details', {
  refresh: function(frm) {
    var today = new Date(); 

    // this is how you get data from form
    var birthDate = new Date(frm.doc.brithday); 

    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear(); var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth(); 
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) { 
      age--; 
    } 

    // use frm.set_value to set value of a field
    frm.set_value('age', age);

    // getting data from form
    var first_name = frm.doc.firstname
    var last_name = frm.doc.lastname
    var full_name = firstname.concat(lastname)  
    
    // setting fullname in form
    frm.set_value('fullname', full_name);
  }        
});
```

---

Above code will make changes in `fullname` and `age` fields on `refresh` event. If you need the changes realtime, you can use the following code. Setting up events on `brithdate` to change `age` and on `firstname` and `lastname` to change `fullname`.

```
frappe.ui.form.on('client_details', {
  brithday: function(frm) {
    var today = new Date(); 

    // this is how you get data from form
    var birthDate = new Date(frm.doc.brithday); 

    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear(); var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth(); 
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) { 
      age--; 
    } 

    // use frm.set_value to set value of a field
    frm.set_value('age', age);
  },
  firstname: function(frm) {
    // getting data from form
    var first_name = frm.doc.firstname
    var last_name = frm.doc.lastname
    var full_name = firstname.concat(lastname)  
    
    // setting fullname in form
    frm.set_value('fullname', full_name);
  },
  lastname: function(frm) {
    // getting data from form
    var first_name = frm.doc.firstname
    var last_name = frm.doc.lastname
    var full_name = firstname.concat(lastname)  
    
    // setting fullname in form
    frm.set_value('fullname', full_name);
  }        
});
```

---

It is good practice to keep `age` and `fullname` fields as `readonly` since they are `computed` and wont be user inputs.